# Double elements in Float arraylist after parsing numbers by numberFormat

Tags: java, casting, number-formatting

I want to parse some Strings (they include some numbers) with same format but different number kind and set these number to their related array. for example having this string: " "positions":[[35.23,436.34],[23.5, 7.1]] I want to put these number into a float array named "this"! and for this string" "indices":[[23,4],[2,1]]" I want to put them into an integer array named "that"!

To do so, I've wrote a generic function with this declaration:

```
       private <E extends Number> voidfunc(ArrayList<E> array, String JSON){
       .
       .
       array.add((E) NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(JSON.substring(...)));
       .
       .
       }
```

this works well and put numbers into array correctly but later, in somewhere in my app I get a "class cast exception. Can not cast Double to Float" trying to do this:

```
       floatArray[i] = temp.get(i);
```

temp have defined as a float arraylist and have filled with above function.

can anybody tell me why it is so, and how can I solve that? I really appreciate that.

Comment: It seems like temp is filled with double. Can you add more relevant code? where you fill temp?

Comment: @baraky Yeah. before executing that line, the elements of temp are Double.

temp is one of the arrays I pass to that generic function and fills there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, `E` is type parameter of generic method.  This type is not known at run time, so cast to this type done with `(E)` is fake and compiler most probably reported warning at this line.  JVM does not check type compatibility during this cast, so it is possible that value of incompatible type will get into the list.  For example, value of `Double` type may be stored in `List<Float>`.  Later, when you try to extract value form the list and cast it to `Float`, `ClassCastException` will occur.

You probably need to change your code like this:

```
private void func (ArrayList <? super Double> array, String JSON)
{
    ...
    array.add (NumberFormat.getInstance ().parse (JSON.substring (...)));
    ...
}

ArrayList <Number> temp = new ArrayList ();
func (temp, json);
floatArray [i] = temp.get (i).floatValue ();
```

Comment: I get this error in get.(i) part. So I cant use sp00m answer. true?

Comment: @alireza Yes you can, but this is less elegant and does not use compiler's ability to check type compatibility.  And you better cast to `Number` rather than `Double`, because `floatValue()` is defined there.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```java
floatArray[i] = ((Double) temp.get(i)).floatValue();
```